# How do I invoke a .cgi file to run, from a .pm file?

Tags: perl, cgi

In my .pm file, I use the content type as text/html, to write the source code of a web-page. I need to write a download code also, and for that I need to specify my content type as "Content-Type:application/x-download". I tried having this in my .pm file itself but the browser gets confused and LITERALLY PRINTS the above quoted line on the site. So, I am gonna write the below download code in a separate .cgi file. Now, I need to call this .cgi file from the .pm file, and I also need to pass arguments to .cgi file. Help please? What I have tried is :

.pm file :

```
...
system('downloadscript.cgi', $fileholder);
...
```

.cgi file :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI ':standard';
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

my $ID = "sample.txt";
my $fileholder = shift;  

if ($ID eq '') {   
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";   
print "You must specify a file to download.";   
} else {  
print "Content-Type:application/x-download\n";   
print "Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=$ID\n\n";  
print $fileholder;  
}
```

When I execute this, nothing happens. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Learn about structuring your code into subroutines and libraries. Instead of running a whole program, load the library and call the specific subroutine in it.

Comment: check server access log and error log.

Comment: What is the point of the .pm file here? It looks to me like your .cgi program is well on the way to being a complete solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

calling cgi file in .pm file doesnt help, create a wrapper of .pm file and call in the cgi file